# Dying Mapbox polygon in accordance with a colored progress bar in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, progress-bar, mapbox, polygon

I am trying to dye `Mapbox` polygon according to my fuel bar. Please find attached the images.

For instance, when I increase or decrease the fuel bar, I want to get the color list from my progress bar and pass these to my polygon drawing class. I should only extract 3 colors.

For example, below polygon colors are wrong. This is because although I don't have a green color in progress bar, my class is dying green polygon on the UI. Do you know how can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

[image]. [image]

Answer (score 1):

`fillColor()` is what you'll need to use.

See https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/draw-a-polygon/ and https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/dds/DrawPolygonActivity.java#L72 specifically.

Pass the fuel bar color value through the `fillColor()` method.'

If you need to get your `FillLayer` to change the color in runtime, you can get it with

```
mapboxMap.getStyle {

                val fillLayer = it.getLayerAs<FillLayer>("fill-layer-id")
                fillLayer?.setProperties(
                        fillColor()
                )

            }
```